# What promises were not fulfilled (meaning were not done) in the Indian Removal Act?

Tags: united-states, native-americans, treaties

I was genuinely wondering what promises were actually fulfilled in the Indian Removal Act. Out of these, it would be especially nice if I could find out whether the 2nd and 8th one were actually fulfilled. Thank you!

These are the promises listed in the [Indian Removal Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Removal_Act) (I obtained this list from an adapted version of [Andrew Jackson's letter to the Cherokee](https://www.paulding.k12.ga.us/cms/lib/GA01903603/Centricity/Domain/2519/primary-source-jackson-cherokee-letter-19765-False.pdf))

> 1st. For an addition to the country already assigned to you west of the Mississippi, and for the conveyance[3](https://cherokeemuseum.com/archives/era/trail-of-tears) of the whole of it, by patent[3](https://cherokeemuseum.com/archives/era/trail-of-tears), in fee simple[3](https://cherokeemuseum.com/archives/era/trail-of-tears). And also for the security of the necessary political rights, and for preventing white persons from trespassing upon you.

> 2nd. For the payment of the full value to each individual, of his possession in Georgia, Alabama, North Carolina and Tennessee.

> 3rd. For the removal, at the expense of the United States, of your whole people; for their subsistence[4](https://www.teachushistory.org/indian-removal/resources/cherokee-tribe-indians-jackson) for a year after their arrival in their new country, and for a gratuity[5] of one hundred and fifty dollars to each person.

> 4th. For the usual supply of rifles, blankets, and kettles.

> 5th. For the investment of the sum of four hundred thousand dollars, in order to secure a permanent annuity[6].

> 6th. For adequate provision[7] for schools, agricultural instruments, domestic animals, missionary establishments, the support of orphans, etc.

> 7th. For the payment of claims[8].

> 8th. For granting pensions[9] to such of your people as have been disabled in the service of the United States.

---

[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Removal_Act) Transfer or sale.

[2](https://www.paulding.k12.ga.us/cms/lib/GA01903603/Centricity/Domain/2519/primary-source-jackson-cherokee-letter-19765-False.pdf) Exclusive right.
[3](https://cherokeemuseum.com/archives/era/trail-of-tears) Fee simple means you have the land forever.
[4](https://www.teachushistory.org/indian-removal/resources/cherokee-tribe-indians-jackson) Food and drink.
[5] Gift.
[6] A fixed payment to be received once a year.
[7] Support with money.
[8] Lawsuits.
[9] Money paid to former soldiers.

I've tried looking on Britannica and official US websites but they haven't helped.

---

[Another source on letter to the Cherokee](https://www.teachushistory.org/indian-removal/resources/cherokee-tribe-indians-jackson)

[Cherokee Museum:Indian Removal Act of 1830](https://cherokeemuseum.com/archives/era/trail-of-tears)

Comment: Where did this list originate? What do the bracketed numbers correspond to? What are the criteria for fulfilment of these "promises"?

Comment: Where have you looked for answers? What did you find? Which specific items did you have trouble finding information on? Good questions demonstrate that some effort put into conducting preliminary research. Documenting that preliminary research helps to avoid duplication of effort by prospective answer writers.

Comment: I've tried looking on Britannica and official US websites but they haven't helped.

Comment: Please cite the letter from which you extract the list to avoid accusatons of plagiarism. Is there a reason the cited Wikipedia article doesn't answer the question?    If you're looking for non-fulfillment, I'd suggest pursuing  Cherokee nation resources rather than US government.  [USCCR](https://www.usccr.gov/files/pubs/2018/12-20-Broken-Promises.pdf) may also be helpful. Good luck

Comment: @MCW Since the web page you linked does not contain the footnotes explaining the referenced terms, I would guess it is not the source being used by the user, but is merely referencing the same primary document, the letter from Jackson.(I suspect the original document is the users homework text or handout due to these explanations) Changing the numbers/adding outside links in the footnotes seems confusing, since that link does not address specific issues raised by the question but appears to hold general information.

Comment: Right off the bat, #1 wasn't done. Many white people simply [never respected Native sovereignty](https://www.okhistory.org/publications/enc/entry?entry=IN016) in Indian Territory (now eastern Oklahoma), on the theory that the USA government really had the ultimate authority over it, and if push came to shove would take their interests over those of the Natives. They ended up being right.

Comment: Are there any other websites that can help?